# white space on the right side, only on mobile

Tags: html, css

I get this vertical white line on the right side of my page.
it's only happening on mobile. found it using device tool bar: https://jood19.sg-host.com/

I designed the website "mobile-first". only used media queries for desktop.

I've tried, without success, the following code

```
html body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

can you recommend something?

Comment: Try adding the body/html width as a viewport length --> `width: 100vw;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your image has a set width which happens to be wider than the mobile screen.

You can keep the set width if you add a max-width to the image. This will mean it will be the same size as you originally had except for when the screen is too small for that and then it will take up the full width.

```
.about-section img {
    width: 28rem;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting your `.about-section img` on the dev tools seem to remove the whitespace. Tried with 21 rem on mobile screens.

```
.about-section img {
    width: 21rem;
}
```